# Fullcalendar adding event with fixed end time

Tags: events, fullcalendar, addition

This is probably an easy one for those who know this thing. :)

Given this:

```
$(this).fullCalendar('renderEvent',
    {
       title: 'Class',
       start: date,
       end: date.setHours(2),
       allDay: false 
    }, true );
```

Which doesn't work... what's the syntax for setting the end time to two hours past the time that was clicked on?  So if the user clicks on 8 AM, I want it to automatically end two hours later, at 10 AM.

And... is it possible to make it so the event length cannot be resized?  As in, remove the little UI thing that they can click on to increase or decrease the size?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out (mostly).  in the above example, `end: date.setHours(2)` of course doesn't work. Upon inspecting the date object passed into `dayClick`, I found `fromNow` and when I tried `date.fromNow(2)`, it worked!

The only issue I have now (unrelated to my original question) is that it's prompting me for the event name even though I'm specifying it in the code.  Here's the final, working version of what I posted above:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent',
     {
        id: 0,
        title: 'Class',
        start: date,
        end: date.fromNow(2),
        allDay: false
     }, true );
```